# Why does yaml.dump add quotes this key-value pair

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

I'm trying to write a new entry to a rails database.yml and for some reason I'm getting quotes around this entry

db_yml => {'new_env' => {'database' => 'database_name', '<<' => '*defaults' }}
File.open("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/database.yml", "a") {|f| YAML.dump(db_yml, f)}

returns

```
---
 new_env: 
   database: database_name
   "<<": "*defaults"
```

I don't know why the "---" and the quotes around the defaults are returned, any thoughts on how to prevent?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

<< and * have special meaning in YAML.
Quotes are used to show that << is not [merge](http://yaml.org/type/merge.html) and * is not an [alias](http://www.yaml.org/spec/current.html#id2530982).

Answer (score 1):

the --- is just to mark the start of YAML dump.

The double quote around `<<` it's because can be interpretate in YAML format. So it's escape.

Comment: so what if I wanted to write to the file but not have quotes there and not have the lines that mark the start of the dump? Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You can't if you want use some reseved character